# Problema con el uso de variables

Tags: variables

Tengo una duda, a lo mejor es una tontería pero he estado intentando varias maneras y nada mas no puedo. Deseo usar la variable lo en el método de envío a otro `activity` pero no me deja, se supone que en el `onLocationChanged` luego de todo el procedimiento la variable lo guarda el valor en string del cálculo de distance y ese valor necesito enviarlo a otro layout, peeero no es así, de hecho al tratar de escribir la variable en el `i.putExtra` no aparece. Dejo una imagen a ver si es mas entendible.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc ) {
    Double lati =  loc.getLatitude();
    Double loni =  loc.getLongitude();
    double d = Double.parseDouble(ubica);
    double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(new LatLng(loni,lati), new LatLng(d,d));
    String lo = Double.toString(distance);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Información Detallada",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // num1(marker.getSnippet());
    for (MarkerInfo markerInfo : list) {
        if (marker.getTitle().contentEquals(markerInfo.name)) {
            String Abc;
            Abc = marker.getTitle();

            Intent i = new Intent(this, detalle.class);
            i.putExtra("firstName", Abc);
            i.putExtra("lastName", markerInfo.population);
            i.putExtra("img", markerInfo.imageURL);
            i.putExtra("website",markerInfo.web);
            i.putExtra("ubica",markerInfo.ubica);
            i.putExtra("distan", lo );
            startActivity(i);

            break;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `lo` está siendo **declarada** e inicializada dentro del método `onLocationChanged`, por lo tanto no puedes acceder a esta desde el método `onInfoWindowClick`.

Para acceder a `lo` desde ambos métodos, debes **declararla** a nivel de clase (afuera del método `onLocationChanged`) y luego puedes usarla en cualquiera de tus métodos.

El código queda como a continuación *(obviando las partes que no son relevantes con `...`)*

```
private String lo;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    ...
    lo = Double.toString(distance);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    ...
    i.putExtra("distan", lo);
    ...
```

Comment: Entiendo y en efecto ese era el problema muchas gracias

Comment: @XavierEspinosa perfecto, podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada?

Comment: Listo, disculpa apenas me estoy acostumbrando al sitio pero ya quedó. Muchas gracias